# Are women permitted to go near the graves or graveyards to perform Jiarat (Dua) for the dead?

Tags: sharia, women, grave

In my country women are not allowed to go near graves and perform Jiarat (Dua).
But men are allowed to do that.

What is the Islamic position on this? Are there any references regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is permissible for women to visit graves as long as they can contain themselves and this is supported by the Hadith of Aisha (RA) in which she states that she used to visit the grave of her father and that of the Prophet(PBUH).

> Aisha ra said: Whenever I entered the house in which Prophet (Peace be upon him) and my father (i.e. Abu Bakr ra) are buried, I used to take off my sheet (from head) thinking that it’s only my father and husband (whom I am visiting), however By Allah! When Umar (ra) got buried with them, I never went inside without being fully covered, this is because of being ashamed of Umar (ra) [Musnad Ahmed bin Hanbal, Volume No. 6, Page No. 202, Hadith # 25701]

Most people may not agree to this but as far as I know, women are forbidden to perform the rituals of burying someone but they may visit the grave after words.

For more information, refer to, [Why women cannot go to graves? - Islam helpline](http://islamhelpline.net/node/2368).